# Как максимально быстро постоянно парсить сайт на предмет появления новой информации

Tags: python, парсер

Есть сайт, на нем раз в несколько часов появляются статьи, заголовки которых выводятся на странице. Хотелось бы максимально быстро узнать, появилась ли новая статья на сайте и получить текст заголовка этой статьи. На данный момент вижу вариант постоянной отправки запроса и получения DOM страницы, но какие еще варианты могут быть ? Можно ли это осуществить с помощью web socket или иным образом ? Задача - максимально быстро получить обновление.

Answer (score -1):

Собственно говоря... у сайта должен быть показатель частоты обновления страниц, который укажет частоту запросов, более высокая частота, грозит добавлением твоего ип в чс (про это даже есть стори у меня), то есть примитивный вариант это запросы к странице мдулем request. Есть альтернатива: rss, email. Большинство сайтов предоставляет возможность подписки по емэйл, в этом случае придётся проверять почтовый ящик, что более цивильно, rss же проще парсить, также меньший шанс нарваться на защиту от ботов.

Comment: На сайте нет подписки по rss и нужные новости не отправляются по email

Comment: будь у меня адрес сайта, то посоветовал бы оптимальный способ на мой взгляд. Так лишь общие инструкции (ну и зря про стори не спросил тогда целую страну в гугле забанили D)

Comment: Догадываюсь что забанили целую подсеть а за ней была страна, если о стори можешь рассказать. Сайт в принципе любой, допустим мне нужно спарсить вот этот сайт https://ria.ru/economy/ и максимально быстро получить заголовок последней страницы, как только его запостили. Но только не через RSS и не через уведомления на e-mail

Comment: тогда только через переодические запросы, но это не комильфо: запросы каждые 15 минут на протяжении суток, заблокируются

Comment: Скорее всего я использую умное решение с request и proxy, нашел вроде хорошие с ротацией. Решение просто с request не примитивное, оно хорошее, но не подойдет для сайтов с защитой